# Unity - Weird Bug , Build vs Build and Run

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build, render

I am working on a unity project , where I apply a `texture` on a `sphere` `game object` . I get a the texture from a **.jpg file**. It is specified that the **.jpg file** isn't placed in `Resources` or `Assets` folder , but on a folder inside the project , where the .exe of the project would be also , after building it . So the path for the **.jpg** is  ***/project-name/Build/texture.jpg*** . In order to access the **.jpg** , I use the `UnityWebRequestTexture` class , which is modified for accessing files on the disk , using also a relative path , as you can see on my code .

```
// For accessing the .jpg and using it as file we use the UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture (see uinty docs)
// The path is a URL , but we modify it to work for local computer with relative path


    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Networking;
    
    public class LoadTexture : MonoBehaviour
    {
    
        Texture2D texture;
        Texture2D texture2;
    
        public GameObject sph;
    
        bool on = false;
       
        public Renderer sphRenderer;
    
        void Start()
        {
    
            sphRenderer = sph.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    
            StartCoroutine(GetText());
    
                IEnumerator GetText()
                {
                    using (UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture("file://" + "/../Build/texture-sphere.jpg")) // Relative path
                    {
                        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
    
                        if (uwr.isNetworkError || uwr.isHttpError)
                        {
                            // Display error
                            Debug.Log(uwr.error);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Get downloaded asset bundle
                            texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
    
    
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    
    
        void Update()
        {
    
            // Implemenation of toggle by pressing T key
    
    
            // Press T
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
                on = !on;
    
    
            if (on)
            {
                
                // Change to white color first
                 sphRenderer.material.color = Color.white;
    
    
                //Resources.Load("texture", typeof(Texture2D));
                // Set the Texture to the SPH Renderer
                sphRenderer.material.mainTexture = texture as Texture2D;
                                     
            }
    
            else if (!on)
            {
                //set texture to null
                sphRenderer.material.mainTexture = null;
    
                // change color to red
                sphRenderer.material.color = Color.red;
    
            }
    
        }
                
    }
```

Essentially what I'm doing is **toggling** **shpere's** appearance between **red color** and the **texture** applied on it , by pressing the `T key` . I came upon a very weird bug :

If I **Build and Run** my project , the **texture** is applied as desired when toggling , but If I click on **.exe** file (*from the same build*) and run it again , it doesn't , just stays white (*cause , as you can see on my code , I first make the sphere white and then apply the texture*) . I've also tried all the possible **build and run** , and **build** combinations by changing locations etc and the problem persists . Also when I hit **play** , in the **Game window** of **unity** **editor** it runs as expected . Only when clicking on the **.exe** is the problem .

I guess , with **Build and Run** , unity still uses editor's `Assets` ? Maybe the devil lies in the **dll**'s or the `Resources` folder ?

I'm posting also images , of the states I said above .

**Build & Run** :
[image]

**when I click on .exe** :
[image]

By the way , color apperas different , cause a `Random.Range` code run .

Comment: I suspect this is a "working directory" problem.  When you "Build" and then run, the "working directory" is the directory the exe is in, and the path to the jpg should be ```./texture.jpg```.  My guess is that "Build and Run" runs the exe but sets the working directory to the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `StreamingAssets` folder is for. Put your runtime-loading graphics in there and access them using the `Application.streamingAssetsPath` variable.

See [the manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) for more info.